# When should Redis HyperLogLog be avoided and why?

Tags: algorithm, redis, hyperloglog

I have some basic ideas of how Redis HyperLogLog works and when to use it.
Before using it I did a test: I `pfadd`ed some consecutive numbers to an HLL entry (to mimic user ids), and Redis soon gave a false positive result. To be exact, if you `pfadd` number 193 to an HLL entry, number 202 would be reported already existing in that entry. You may test it in redis-cli :

```
127.0.0.1:6379> del ns
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> PFADD ns 193
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> PFADD ns 202
(integer) 0
```

I know that HyperLogLog is a probabilistic data structure, but isn't it too easy for HLL to give false positives like this? Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 4):

1. You misunderstood `PFADD`'s reply - it does not indicate existence but rather whether an internal register in the data structure had changed.
2. You also misunderstand HLL's use - it estimates set cardinality (size), not set membership.

For a similar (in the probablistic sense) data structure that does set membership, check Bloom Filters and their Redis implementation, Rebloom (http://rebloom.io).

Comment: Hello @Itamar, sorry for the late reply. But I am still confused. If `PFADD`'s reply indicates internal change and HLL is simply used to estimates cardinality,  then I'd think it is natural to test membership with HLL: add one thing and HLL entry's cardinality changes - that thing exists, otherwise it does not. am I right?